# Что лучше для чата notifySetDataChanged или Diffutil?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Я пишу полноценный чат. Но у меня вопрос что лучше использовать во время переписки `notifySetDataChanged` или `DiffUtil`. Подскажите если кто знает что используют такие приложение как Whatsapp, Telegram, Instagram и другие популярные мессенджеры?

Comment: А какие вообще могут быть аргументы за `notifySetDataChanged`?

Comment: notifySetDataChanged  - это хардкорный способ аля "все удалить и сделать заново!" а DiffUtil - мягкий "давайте найдем изменения и перерисуем только необходимые". еще есть notify отдельных, заранее известных эл-ов и диапозонов, но она была не очень популярна. DiffUtil - менее ресурсо-затратный способ. если у вас 5 эл-во - разницы не увидите. а если у вас 105 элементов - разница сразу видна.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov при каждым новым сообщением notifySetDataChanged обновляет вес recyclerview и это занимает много ресурсов.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю, как работает `notifySetDataChanged`, потому и спрашиваю, с чего вообще его использовать, когда есть DiffUtil)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я получил ответ на свой вопрос :)